# Familial exemption for investment advisor representative

Tags: united-states, licensing, finance, sec

My parents have asked me to trade for them and they offered me a fraction of any profit. My plan is to set up a limited trade agreement and then manage the account's trades.

Before doing so, I want make sure that I will not be in violation of any regulations. Based on my research, I would not need a Series 7 license. Because this is for immediate family, would I also be exempt from registering as an IAR?

All parties and trading accounts are in the US.

Comment: Please indicate for which country you are asking about.